# I'm getting an error when I install npm expo cli on Mac?

Tags: npm, command-line-interface, expo

The following is my command and the output. Please help me figure out why I am getting this error:

```
$ npm install -g expo-cli

npm WARN deprecated nomnom@1.8.1: Package no longer supported. Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.  
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules  
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules  
npm ERR! code EACCES  
npm ERR! errno -13  
npm ERR! syscall access  
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'  
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'  
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',  
npm ERR!   errno: -13,  npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',  
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',  
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }  
npm ERR!   
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.  
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user  
npm ERR!   
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the  
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running  
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
```